# Doesn't back button work with SafeArea View

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Hey I have below screen where I am using `SafeArea` and `BackButton`. Here back button is not working with SafeArea.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue ?

```
class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Expanded(
                          child: new Image.asset('assets/images/profile.jpg',
                              fit: BoxFit.fill, height: 250),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 220, left: 22),
                      child: new Text("Eilly",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 15)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                new Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: new BackButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `MaterialApp` from your build function will do the trick! Use `MaterialApp` only for root page. Use `Scaffold` for routed pages and it will automatically create back button in AppBar.

```
appBar:  PreferredSize(child: AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
  ),
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0)
  )
```

Comment: This is because SafeView prevents Scaffold to collapse with Status bar. SafeView doesn't work well with a custom back button without appbar on notch device. Maybe you should try adding invisible appbar and see if its gets better.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics#complete-example

You need `MaterialApp` as the root of the app.
After that, you can create as many `page widgets` as you want.

Then use `Navigator` to navigate between them.